# Reset Ubuntu 14.04 server to a completely fresh state?

Tags: server, restore, reset

I've had major problems since I updated to 14.04, so now that I've made backups of all the websites and databases that had been running on the server, could you tell me if there is a way to completely reinstall everything - but without USB/CD, i.e. via ssh.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/OverSSH has a guide to installing over SSH using debootstrap. There's an example from serverfault, https://serverfault.com/questions/208128/how-to-remotely-install-linux-via-ssh, of someone doing a very similar process. Their idea of testing the process on a VM first makes lots of sense.

In general, for particular packages/apps you can use `sudo apt-get purge $PKG-NAME` to remove a deb package and all its config files - sometimes apt-get refuses to remove config files that have been altered or directories with other non-install files present. I use `updatedb; locate -e -i $APP-NAME` to find such files. Once purged and config files have been removed then install each app afresh.

Another option is to use `sudo aptitude` (a package management interface to apt-get), say, select all installed apps and choose to remove them (press "-" when on "installed" line of main screen) then find ("/") ubuntu-desktop (or your preferred meta-package) and add it ("+" when the package is highlighted). Now "g" takes you to the install screen to review the package changes and "g" again commits them. This won't remove configuration files but `dpkg-reconfigure` can be used to run the install scripts for packages and return them to defaults.